# How to get one and many files in endpoint in nest.js

Tags: node.js, express, nestjs, endpoint, nodejs-server

I need to get 10 images and 1 txt file in one endpoint in nest.js.
Firstly I used 2 interceptors:

```js
  @Post()
  @UseInterceptors(FilesInterceptor('images'), FileInterceptor('certificate'))
  async create(@Body() createProductDto: CreateProductDto, @UploadedFiles(ProductImageFilesPipe) images: Express.Multer.File[], @UploadedFile() certificate: Express.Multer.File) {
    return await this.productService.create(createProductDto, images, certificate);
  }
```

But every time I send request, I get
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFRxS.png)
After that I tried to use this code:

```js
  @Post()
  @UseInterceptors(FilesInterceptor([{
    name: "images", maxCount: 10
  },
    {
    name: "certificate", maxCount: 1
  }])
  async create(@Body() createProductDto: CreateProductDto, @UploadedFiles(ProductImageFilesPipe) images: Express.Multer.File[], @UploadedFile() certificate: Express.Multer.File) {
    return await this.productService.create(createProductDto, images, certificate);
  }
```

But it isn't compiled because of wrong type.
Now I'm stuck and need help of brave Stack Overflowers)

Comment: try to implement it as indicated in the documentation
https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/file-upload#multiple-files